# Restoring Django Model Field after accidental deletion

Tags: django, migration

I have an existing events model in my django app that lists events. The events has a poster field that was using the models.ImageField for storing the related poster. The uploading of events was controlled from the admin only so no public uploading. The database had about 50 entries of events and things were working fine.
Since the images was getting heavier, I tried adding the sorl.thumnail to django. In my models.py file, I imported the ImageField from sorl.thumbnails and added it to the poster field.

When I ran makemigrations, it reported 'alter field poster' Then I ran migrate and on reloading, I do not see the Poster field in the admin. 
Even the existing events have lost the poster field and the images cannot be shown in the templates too.

I have reverted the changes and run migrations again, but the poster field is still not visible. Is there any way to restore the model, and reconnect it with existing poster images?
I am using python 3.5 and django 1.11 Everything else works fine, this seems like a stupid mistake for the sake of getting a little more speed.

Will be grateful for any suggestions.

Here is what my Events model looks like`class Events(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    note = RichTextUploadingField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=EVENT_TYPES, verbose_name=_('Event Category'))
    date_from = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, blank=False)
    date_to = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, blank=False)
    poster = models.ImageField(upload_to='Programs/', blank=True, max_length=100, width_field=None, height_field=None)
    video = models.URLField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    capacity = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True)
    venue = GeopositionField(blank=True)`

Admin.py is simply a register function

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('title', 'date', 'venue', 'category')
```

admin.site.register(Event, EventAdmin)

Comment: in the database is the poster field with the data is available? if not you cannot get back those. as those are already deleted from the database

Comment: I can see the uploaded files. The django admin area does not have the poster field anymore. I have tried restoring the models.py to its initial state and then running migrations, it still does not bring back the poster field. I have added the event model definition

Comment: show the code of the admi.py and tell me now what you have and what you need actually

Comment: Updated the question with the admin.py. It is a simple register function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it doesn't seem likely to recover a lost field with the data intact. I am using MySQL for the project. So here is what I did after making all possible efforts to salvage it. 
First I deleted all migrations in the applications/migrations folder. Then I changed the name of the field in the model. Then when I ran makemigrations, it showed me the the message 'Alter Field in Events' I proceeded with migrate after that.

It is good to tell you that I am on the Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu Server. So I had to reboot the instance and then reload the admin page. But the changes in the model admin were still not visible.

Then I had to stop the server, and start it after 5 minutes. This changed the public IP and on reloading the site, I saw the ImageUpload field in admin. The rest of the data was intact. Now I just have to re-upload the images in the respective events. This is not the proper solution that I was expecting, but this seems to be the best that could be done.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Note there is no need to add [solved] devices or similar to the title, we don't do that here. If this answer turns out to be the most satisfying solution, you can click the adjacent tick icon to self-accept, if you wish.